# ahk error else with no matching if, what's wrong?

Tags: autohotkey

hi my autohotkey script seems to be wrong , but i checked carefully the brackets and i think is okay, but i keep getting error else with no matching if, is there something that i missed?

```
    loot1()
{
    ImageSearch,violetX, violetY, 266, 141, 579, 527, C:\image\loot.png
    If ErrorLevel  {
    mobs1()    
}
    else If ErrorLevel=0 {

            mousemove(%violetX%,%violetY%)
            mouseclick, left
            return
    }
    else 
    {
        sleep, 100
            return
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use OTB with traditional if put the brace in this line `else If ErrorLevel=0 {` on a new line.

Comment: Your inconsistent and non-standard indenting makes understanding and troubleshooting your code more difficult than it needs to be

Answer (score 0):

You should use just `If`, because there is no previous `If` to match your `Else if`.

Example:

```
if (condition1)
{
    // executed only if "condition1" equals true
}
else if (condition2)
{
    // executed only if "condition1" was false and "condition2" equals true
}
else
{
    // executed only if both "condition1" and "condition3" equals false
}
```

**Edit, perhaps this is the right answer:**

```
loot1()
{
    ImageSearch,violetX, violetY, 266, 141, 579, 527, C:\image\loot.png
    If ErrorLevel  
    {
    mobs1()    
    }
    else If ErrorLevel=0 
    {
        mousemove(%violetX%,%violetY%)
        mouseclick, left
        return
    }
    else 
    {
        sleep, 100
        return
    }
}
```

There was a missing bracket, you should indent your code for better visualization.

Comment: There is, it's just somewhat hidden.